# When inserting a value into my 2-3 tree, I am not getting an expected value

Tags: java

I am currently creating a 2-3 tree but I ran into a problem. I looked all over online for examples on how to insert a value into my 2-3 tree and I still am having trouble. The error I received is that it expected the value 9, but it was 0. I do not understand why it did not insert 9 in the first place because since 9 is the first value to be inserted in the tree, in my insert method where I put:

```
 if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(x);
        return true;
 }
```

would not it just create a new node with the value 9 and it will just work?

Here is my node class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Node {

private Node parent;
private Node leftChild;
private Node middleChild;
private Node rightChild;
private Node fourthChild;
int smallKey;
int largeKey;
// creates nodes
ArrayList<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
// creates list of numbers to insert into node
ArrayList<Integer> nodeData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public Node(int x) {
    parent = null;
    nodeData.add(x);
}

public Node(int x, Node leftChild, Node middleChild, Node rightChild, Node fourthChild)
{
    parent = null;
    nodeData.add(x);
    leftChild = children.get(0);
    middleChild = children.get(1);
    rightChild = children.get(2);
    fourthChild = children.get(3);
    smallKey = nodeData.get(0);
    largeKey = nodeData.get(2);
}

public void addChild(Node newNode) {
    newNode.parent = this;
    this.children.add(newNode);
}

public boolean isLeaf() {
    return children.isEmpty();
}

public String toString() {
    if (this.nodeData.size() >= 2) {
        return Integer.toString(this.smallKey) + " " + 
        Integer.toString(this.largeKey);
    } else {
        return Integer.toString(this.smallKey);
    }
}

public Node addData(Node node, int x) {
    if(x < node.smallKey)
    {
        node.leftChild = addData(node.leftChild, x); 
    }
    else if(x > node.largeKey)
    {
        node.rightChild = addData(node.rightChild, x);
    }
    else
    {
        node.middleChild = addData(node.middleChild, x);
    }
    return node;
}

Node findNode(Node currentNode, int x) {
    if (currentNode.isLeaf()) {
        return currentNode;
    }
    if (x < currentNode.smallKey) {
        return findNode(currentNode.leftChild, x);
    } else if (x > currentNode.largeKey) {
        return findNode(currentNode.rightChild, x);
    } else {
        return findNode(currentNode.middleChild, x);
    }
}
}
```

My 2-3 Class:

```
public class TwoThreeTree {
Node root;

public TwoThreeTree() {
    root = null;
}

public boolean insert(int x) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(x);
        return true;
    }
    Node insertNode = root.findNode(root, x);
    insertNode.addData(root, x);
    if (insertNode.nodeData.size() == 3) {
        insertNode.addData(root, x);
        root.split(insertNode);
    }
    return true;
}

public String search(int x) {
    Node searchNode = root.findNode(root, x);
    return searchNode.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
public class TwoThreeTreeGivenTests
{
  @Test
  public void singleNodeTree()
  {
  TwoThreeTree t = new TwoThreeTree();
  int val = 9;
  t.insert(val);
  String expected = "9";

  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));
  val = 8;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));
  val = 10;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));


  val = 15;
  t.insert(val);
  expected = "9 15";
  val = 9;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));
  val = 8;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));

  t = new TwoThreeTree();
  val = 15;
  t.insert(val);
  val = 9;
  t.insert(val);
  val = 9;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));
  val = 8;
  assertEquals(expected, t.search(val));
  }
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].  There is a lot of code, did you troubleshoot it so you can point where the issue is, roughly?

Answer (score 0):

`Node.toString()` (which is called by `TwoThreeTree.search()`) returns a string with `smallKey` or `smallKey` and `largeKey` but both variables are never set (and default to 0).

Regarding the constructor

`public Node(int x, Node leftChild, Node middleChild, Node rightChild, Node fourthChild)`

which would set `smallKey` and `largeKey` there are a few problems:

1. It is never called
2. if it would be called it would fail with an exception because it tries to retrieve items from `children` and `nodeData` which are `ArrayList`s containing 0 and 1 item respectively at the time of the `get()` calls in the constructor.
3. if items could be retrieved they are set to local variables/parameters `leftChild`, `middleChild`, ... instead of the member variables.

   To ensure that member variables are set they must be prefixed with `this.` here to avoid shadowing. This third point doesn't apply to `smallKey` and `largeKey` because they aren't shadowed by local variables/parameters.

Comment: In my node method in the Node class I set  smallKey = nodeData.get(0);
and largeKey = nodeData.get(2);  Does that not work?

Comment: @Kevin This is not a method but a constructor. I have updated my answer to explain details about the problems with it.